# Need to remove advertising identifier from facebook sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I need to remove adsupport dependency from facebook iOS-SDK because I am not showing any Adds in my app and Apple is rejecting apps if there is advertising identifier but not displaying ads in the app. Is there any possible solution? Kindly check this link  http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/03/apples-latest-crackdown-apps-pulling-the-advertising-identifier-but-not-showing-ads-are-being-rejected-from-app-store/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try submitting your app again. It should go through now.
[EDIT]: Copied from my own answer:

Everything has come to its usual state now. Simply upload your binary as you've been doing this while, and broadly classify IDFA in two categories:

publisher: You use third-party ad-networks library to display ad. Choose the 1st option in IDFA -> "Serve advertisements within the app". You're a publisher since you show ads, but do not perform advertising for your own app.

Advertiser: You use third-party libraries to track conversions for your app, as well as track 'goals' in your app. You directly do not show ads in your app. Choose the 2nd & 3rd option in IDFA -> "Attribute this app installation to a previously served ad". AND "Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement".

Mixed: You track conversions for your app, as well as display ads in your app. Choose all three options.